# Channel Categories: Display all categories so each parent is a header and children are a list

Tags: categories, parent, child-categories, category-name

I am displaying all of a channel's parent and child categories. The client's design is kinda tricky so the goal is each parent group is in a row, each parent name is in a tag and its children are in a list...

```
<div class="row">
   <h3>Breakfast</h3>
   <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Bakery</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <h3>Lunch</h3>
   <ul>
      <li>Sandwiches</li>
      <li>Salads</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have *kinda* output this result with channel categories...

```
<div class="row">
   {exp:channel:categories channel="catering" style="linear"}
      {if "{parent_id}" == 0}
         <h3>{category_name}</h3>
      {if:else}
         <li>{category_name}</li>
      {/if}
   {/exp:channel:categories}
</div>
```

It comes out like...

```
<div class="row">
   <h3>Breakfast</h3>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Bakery</li>
   <h3>Lunch</h3>
      <li>Sandwiches</li>
      <li>Salads</li>
</div>
```

But how do I get each parent group properly wrapped in a `<div>` and the `<li>` items wrapped in `<ul></ul>` tags? Are there more advanced conditionals I need to be using?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... This can be confusing.

Can you try this, please?

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="catering" style="linear"}
    {if parent_id == 0 OR count == 1}
        {if count > 1 AND count != total_results}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {/if}
        <div class="row">
            <h3>{category_name}</h3>
            <ul>
    {/if}
    {if parent_id != 0}
        <li>{category_name}</li>
    {/if}
    {if count == total_results}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confusing indeed, but yes, that pretty much did the trick.

Except the parent category was repeating as the first item in the list, so I added `&& parent_id != 0` to the second `{if parent_id}`

This is the final working code...

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="catering" style="linear"}
    {if parent_id == 0 OR count == 1}
        {if count > 1 AND count != total_results}
            </ul>
            </div>
        {/if}

        <div class="row">
        <h3>{category_name}</h3>
        <ul>
    {/if}
    {if parent_id && parent_id != 0}
        <li>{category_name}</li>
    {/if}
    {if count == total_results}
        </ul>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I moved your update into the answer. Can you please, close this comment and mark the answer? Thanks!